# Lookup index of CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexing, cllocationcoordinate2d

I have reordered an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D by longitude.

I then want to lookup the index of the reordered elements in the original array.

However, when using the index(of: ) functionality, I am getting the following error message: "Cannot invoke 'index' with an argument list of type '(of: CLLocationCoordinate2D)'"

Any ideas how I can lookup indices of CLLocationCoordinate2D in an array?

```
let sortedArrayOfCoords = arrayOfCoordinates.sorted(by: { $0.longitude < $1.longitude })

print("sorted coord array: \(sortedArrayOfCoords)")

// lookup ordered coordinatess in old unordered arrays to get selections in order of longitude

for element in 0...sortedArrayOfCoords.count - 1 {

    let selectionNumber = arrayOfCoordinates.index(of: sortedArrayOfCoords[element])

    orderedArrayOfSelections.append(selectionNumber)
}
```

Comment: changed the for loop to enumerated type, did not get this error, but then you can directly compare two CLLocationCoordinate2D objects as equals operator is not defined for it.

Comment: @RakshithNandish thanks. Would that mean me using for (element, coord) in sortedArrayOfCoords.enumerated() and seeing which elements in my original array agree with the coord?

Comment: Yup should work, but you will need to write a function that compares two CLLocationCoordinate2D objects.